# Paste an entire cut line at the end of another line in vim

Tags: command-line, vim

I cut a line with <kbd>dd</kbd> and then I want to paste the entire line at the end of another line. But the problem is that because <kbd>dd</kbd> cuts the entire line, it's including the newline character probably too.

And so when I paste via <kbd>p</kbd>, it automatically puts it on the next line. And if I do <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>, it puts it before the line I'm trying to paste on.

So is there a way to paste the entire line I cut at the end of a line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To cut a line without new line, you can press `d$` or `D` from cursor location. 
To paste it at the end of another line, you can go to its end and just press `p`. In case, if you are not able to paste the line as you expected, you can go to the end of line where you wanted to paste. Then, press `i` and then press `<C-R>` (Control-R) and `"` (double quotes).  Your recently cut or copied text will be pasted.

Answer (score 3):

After you pasted your line after your current one via <kbd>p</kbd> just press another <kbd>j</kbd> in your previous line to join the two lines, thus eliminating your unwanted line feed...

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I can think up for now is:

```
A<C-r>+
```

It means: enable insert mode at the end of line and paste the content of the register `+`.

It will also paste newline. `dd` is simply operating on full lines (short for `1dd`).

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, often the use case is as follows: You want to delete a complete line (including the newline, so `d$` / `D` don't work, as the leave behind an empty line), but paste this at the end or inside some existing line, without creating a new one.

My [UnconditionalPaste plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3355) provides several mappings that automatically convert the register contents to the desired use case. Your example would be `dd`, move to target line, `$gcp`. `gcp` is the mapping for *characterwise paste*.